# Using Selenium and chromedriver, how to change the windows taskbar icon?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using selenium and chromedriver in a windows and c# environment, I am wanting to change the windows taskbar icon from it's default window tray icon to an alternative. Can this be done without recompiling the chromedriver with the icon in it built into the assembly?

An example image of the default icon is shown below;
[image]

I have considered using a theme and applying that on load but they do not appear to be able to change the icon.

For background reference, if it helps to know why I want to do this it is because I am using Selenium to perform some automation in conjunction with a regular person user who is using it as a normal browser. I have a few browsers open and am looking to make each browser more easily distinguishable to the user.

Comment: Do you want to change the taskbar icon or the "tray" icon (i.e., the icon in the notification area of the taskbar-by the clock and the sound volume). This might give you some ideas https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150812-00/?p=91831/

Comment: Taskbar icon is the goal. (If I get desperate I could try the notification area, but that's a bit unnatural)...I had a quick look through the link, Im not sure its got the answer but its lead me a few places (not confident though).

Answer (score 0):

If you run Chrome in app mode it will display the web page's icon on the task bar. Try this for example from a run prompt: Chrome.exe --app=https://google.com

You can pass parameters to ChromeDriver. Here is a list:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Example in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67774025/2382032