# Unable to start Chrome with "application" mode (Python-Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch chrome in "application" mode but can't seem to achieve it.

My script is as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--app')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\vm\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Can someone please advise?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't get it about "application" mode can you explain it!

Comment: you can refer to the link for an example
https://technastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/messenger_in_browser-window_and_app.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done similar kind of project. To open the chromedriver in 'Application Mode' you have to specify the url with --app arguments. For example:

`options.add_argument("--app=https://www.youtube.com")`